# Refresh Shell with localized text

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, refresh

I'm trying to change the language of my java programm.
Here is the simplified main frame :

[image]

I managed to change the language with the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and the [RessourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).
And also to get the click on the flag with the Mouse Listener, like this :

```
 imgFrFlag.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
 {
   @Override
   public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {
   }
   @Override
   public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {
   }
   @Override
   public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {
     ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", french);
     System.out.println("french click");
   }
 });
```

But what i would like to do now is to change the reload the window and change the text displayed after the button has been pressed.
Any clue how to do that simply?